# How do I push `sed` matches to the shell call in the replacement pattern?

Tags: sed

I need to replace several URLs in a text file with some content dependent on the URL itself. Let's say for simplicity it's the first line of the document at the URL.

What I'm trying is this:

```
sed "s/^URL=\(.*\)/TITLE=$(curl -s \1 | head -n 1)/" file.txt
```

This doesn't work, since `\1` is not set. However, the shell is getting called. Can I somehow push the `sed` match variables to that subprocess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed - pass match to external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719011/sed-pass-match-to-external-command). Although this question is older than the proposed duplicate, that duplicate does have working answers, while for this one even the accepted answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are trying to call an external command from inside the replacement pattern of a sed substitution. I dont' think it can be done, the $... inside a pattern just allows you to use an already existent (constant) shell variable.

I'd go with Perl, see the /e option in the [search-replace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) operator (s/.../.../e).

**UPDATE**: I was wrong, sed plays nicely with the shell, and it allows you do to that. But, then, the backlash in `\1` should be escaped. Try instead:

```
sed "s/^URL=\(.*\)/TITLE=$(curl -s \\1 | head -n 1)/" file.txt
```

Comment: It works, try it with $(date) inside the replacement pattern.

Comment: Ha, sed is more powerfull than I believed. 
Then, try escaping the backlash with \\1

Comment: I would have expected that to evaluate the `$(...)` expression *first*, before invoking sed; so curl would try to download the URL "`\1`".  And some of your other backslashes surely got eaten, since you were using double quotes.

Comment: oh no, this would be exactly what I was searching for over an hour, only the old sed v4.1.5 from 2006 does not seem to support this:( (tried both $() syntax and backticks ``)

Comment: Thanks, i did search for an hour, this is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 4):

The accept answer is just plain wrong.  Proof:

Make an executable script `foo.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $* 1>&2
```

Now run it:

```
$ echo foo | sed -e "s/\\(foo\\)/$(./foo.sh \\1)/"
\1
$
```

The `$(...)` is expanded **before** *sed* is run.

Comment: you ahve too many backslashes, and the capturnign group is empty..   echo foo | sed "s/\\(foo\\)/$(./foo.sh \\1)/"

Comment: The parameter to the script is still `\1` instead of `foo`. The number of backslashes does not change anything in this case: both `echo afoos | sed -e "s/\(foo\)/x/"` and `echo afoos | sed -e "s/\\(foo\\)/x/"` output `axs`. This answer is right.

Comment: `(echo "a a a a a a") | sed "s/a/$(echo $RANDOM)/g"` -- this is a probably simpler to understand example that replaces each instance of `a` with a random number (using `$RANDOM`), but all replacements are the same number because the `$(...)` shell expansion happens before the `sed` execution and only one random number was generated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed "s/^URL=\(.*\)/\1/" file.txt | while read url; do sed "s@URL=\($url\)@TITLE=$(curl -s $url | head -n 1)@" file.txt; done
```

If there are duplicate URLs in the original file, then there will be n^2 of them in the output. The @ as a delimiter depends on the URLs not including that character.

Comment: This, unlike the accepted answer, seems like it *ought* to work.  Well, except for the backslashes inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but making sure people don't get thrown off by the answers here -- this *can* be done in **gnu sed** using the `e` command.   The following, for example, decrements a number at the beginning of a line:

```
echo "444 foo" | sed "s/\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)/expr \1 - 1 | tr -d '\n'; echo \"\2\";/e"
```

will produce:

```
443 foo
```