# Split multiple fields per line to separate lines using sed, retaining line prefix

Tags: sed

Last Friday I got a problem, to transform a text to another format. On that machine, only gnu sed is available, no awk (strange, I know). And I know nothing about perl. so I am looking for a sed only solution.

the file content is:

```
a  yao.com sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com unee.net 21cn.com iop.com foo.com bar.com baz.net happy2all.com
d  kinge.net
```

the required output, (should be a new file) is:

```
a  yao.com 
a  sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com 
c  unee.net 
c  21cn.com 
c  iop.com
c  foo.com
c  bar.com
c  baz.net
c  happy2all.com
d  kinge.net
```

I tried a lot, also searched famous sed oneliner, but I cannot make it... can someone help me?

Comment: You could write this in a Perl or Python script in a few lines.  I know you said sed only, but it might not be ideal for this.  I could be wrong too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The thing is..well a long story, I make it short. Only one of my colleague and I are responsible for some jobs on that machine. both of us know sed, (well not expert level), and a little awk. We don't know python or perl. I am about learn python. If this script was written by python or perl, in case some new change request comes, we have to come here and ask again. If it is with sed. we could understand how it worked, and change it in future by ourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not easy job for sed, particularly, an one liner. however you mentioned "gnu sed". I see the light!

gnu sed supports `s/.../.../ge` which is useful for this situation:

```
kent$  sed -r 's@(^[a-z]+) (.*)@echo "\2"\|sed "s# #\\n\1  #g"\|sed "/^$/d"@ge' file  
a  yao.com
a  sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com
c  unee.net
c  21cn.com
c  iop.com
c  foo.com
c  bar.com
c  baz.net
c  happy2all.com
d  kinge.net
```

short explanation:

1. the outer sed is `sed -r 's@..x..@..y..@ge' file`   the `ge` allows us pass matched part to external commands
2. The `..y..` part is done by the magic of `ge`. I pass `\2` to another `sed` (via `echo`) : `sed "s# #\\n\1 #g"` this sed replace all space with `\n + \1 + space`
3. in original file, there is `\n` on each line (ending), so there are empty lines in the result of step 2 (above step), we need remove those empty lines `"/^$/d"`
4. finally, the substitution in step 1, (the outer sed), could be done, and we get the result.

check `info sed` for the `s/../../ge`

edit, added the double spaces as OP commented.

Comment: don't know about "ge" of gnu sed. it worked!!! a little problem is in output I need double spaces between "a,b,c.." and domain. but I can fix it by adding another space after "\\n\1". My problem solved. Thank you..

Answer (score 6):

Interesting problem:

```bsh
$ sed -r 's/(\w+\.\w+)/>  &/2g;:a s/^([a-z]+)(.*)>/\1\2\n\1/g;ta' file
a  yao.com 
a  sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com 
c  unee.net 
c  21cn.com 
c  iop.com 
c  foo.com 
c  bar.com 
c  baz.net 
c  happy2all.com
d  kinge.net
```

**Edit:**

It works by using two substitutions.

The first puts a `>` before the URLs that need flattening as a holding character:

```bsh
$ sed -r 's/(\w+\.\w+)/>  &/2g' file
a  yao.com >  sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com >  unee.net >  21cn.com >  iop.com >  foo.com >  bar.com ...
d  kinge.net
```

The second basically replaces the holding `>` with a newline *(uses conditional branching)*:

```bsh
$ sed -r ':a s/^([a-z]+)(.*)>/\1\2\n\1/g;ta'
```

Comment: @FredrikPihl thanks, yeah it's an interesting problem when limited to only `sed`. Easily done with `bash` or `awk` but no fun `:P`

Comment: Your solution works too.  What I do like is, single sed line, neat! What I don't like is, replace with "#" part. It makes the solution not generic. but it does the job for my current problem. thank you. Upvote your answer..

Comment: @Imagination thanks. Good point `#` is a valid URL character, I have changed the holding character to `>` which isn't valid so the answer is now generic.

Comment: what is meaning of `/2g` , instead of `/g`

Comment: It means instead of putting the `>` character before every URL only put it before the second onwards *(we don't need to move the first onto a newline)*. [See this for a better explanation](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8).

Answer (score 1):

As other have noted, a sed solution is tricky so I thought I post a bash-dito:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a array
do
    for i in ${array[@]:1}
    do
        echo ${array[0]} $i
    done
done < input
```

output:

```
a yao.com
a sina.com
b kongu.com
c polm.com
c unee.net
c 21cn.com
c iop.com
c foo.com
c bar.com
c baz.net
c happy2all.com
d kinge.net
```

Comment: yes, I was thinking in this way too if I cannot find a short sed line. thank you. up

Answer (score 1):

Here is a true sed-only script that works. I've written it below as a file that is called by sed on the command line, but it could all be typed on the command line or all entered into a separate script as well:

Save the following as sedscript (or whatever you want to call it). Explanation follows the output.

```
:start
    h
    s/\(.\ \ [^ ]*\).*/\1/
    t continue
    d
:continue
    p
    x
    s/\(.\ \)\ [^ ]*\(\ .*\)/\1\2/
    t start
    d
```

Now run `sed -f sedscript myfile.txt`

With your example above saved as myfile.txt, the following is output:

```
a  yao.com
a  sina.com
b  kongu.com
c  polm.com
c  unee.net
c  21cn.com
c  iop.com
c  foo.com
c  bar.com
c  baz.net
c  happy2all.com
d  kinge.net
```

Sed has a pattern buffer (where you normally work with `s/a/b/` kinds of commands) and a hold buffer. In this script, information is swapped back and forth to the hold buffer to retain the unedited part of a line while working on another part.

`:start` = label to enable jumping

`h` = swap the pattern buffer (current line) into the hold buffer

`s/\(.\ \ [^ ]*\).*/\1/` = While the full line is safe in the hold buffer, strip everything after the first domain, leaving the first desired line (e.g. "a  yao.com").

`t continue` = if the previous command resulted in a substitution, jump to the "continue" label

`d` = if we didn't jump, that means we're done. Delete the pattern buffer and proceed to the next line of the file.

`:continue` = label for the previous jump

`p` = print out the pattern buffer (e.g. "a  yao.com")

`x` = swap the pattern buffer with the hold buffer (could also use `g` to simply copy the hold buffer over the pattern buffer)

`s/\(.\ \)\ [^ ]*\(\ .*\)/\1\2/` = The full original string has now been swapped into the pattern buffer - strip off the domain we just dealt with (e.g. "yao.com")

`t start` = if that wasn't the last domain, start the script over with the new, shortened string.

`d` = if that was the last domain, delete the pattern buffer and continue to the next line in the file.

Comment: By the way, this is the site I always hit when faced with a sed challenge (and this was certainly a challenge!): http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+\s+)\S+)\s+/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner (for some definition of "one") that does it.  It should work on any sed but I've only tested it with gnu sed.

```
sed ':l;s/\(^\|\n\)\([^ \n]\)  \([^ \n][^ \n]*\) /\1\2  \3\ 
\2  /;t l'
```

That's a literal newline after the `\3\`.

Explanation:

1. A literal newline can be included in the replacement by escaping it with a backslash.
2. The `:l` makes a label called `l`.
3. The `t l` loops to the label `l` if a substitution was made.
4. The `s` command operates on the pattern space buffer which initially contain the input line. After the `s` command, the pattern space buffer contains the result of the substitution, including the newline. The second and subsequent times through the loop, the `s` command gets the entire pattern space buffer, including any newlines added in earlier substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat inputFile.txt | sed -e 's/\([^\ ]*\)\(\ *\)\([^\ ]*\)\(\ *\)\([^\ ]*\)\(\ *\)\([^\ ]*\)\(\ *\)\([^\ ]*\)\(\ *\)/\1 \3\n\1 \5\n\1 \7\n\1 \9/' | grep -vE "^..$"
```

Works on my Ubuntu 12.10.

Explanation:

- divides it to 2 groups: group with text and group with empty chars
- repeats group 1 (with first char) and even groups (with text)
- currently works for 4 texts separated by empty chars

finally, removes lines that contained empty "second" group.

Another try with BASH (execute as "script.sh inputFile.txt"):

```
#!/bin/bash

firstParams=`cat $1 | sed -e 's/\([^\ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1/'`
count=1
for MY1 in $firstParams
do
    # print line number ${count} and filter params from the second one forth
    restParams=`cat $1 | sed -n "${count}p" | sed -e 's/\([^\ ]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'`
    for MY2 in $restParams
    do
        echo "$MY1 $MY2"
    done
    count=$(($count+1))
done
```

Comment: This method will only work if the number of "[a-z]+.[abc]+ groups are less than or equal to 9.

Comment: Thank you Rostislav. Here I tested your command with the example on my local laptop. It worked. But didn't work with real file. In real file, there could be basically any number of domains in each line. I just copied a few lines as example. sorry if that information mislead you. Thanks again. I upvoted you answer. Can you make some changes so that it could handle any number of domains?

Comment: I updated question, added some more domains. hope it is clear now

Comment: My first comment updated with BASH version.
However, I found BASH solution below with "array" much nicer :-).

Comment: On the other hand, my BASH solution should work on older BASH version either...I hope so.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
sed -r -n 's/^([a-z])\ \ ([0-9a-z.]*)\ ([0-9a-z .]*)/\1  \2\n\1  \3/p'
```

It will convert each line of the form

```
c  polm.com unee.net 21cn.com iop.com foo.com bar.com baz.net happy2all.com
```

into

```
c  polm.com
c  unee.net 21cn.com iop.com foo.com bar.com baz.net happy2all.com
```

each time it is run.

So the next time it is run on the output of the previous sed this will become

```
c  polm.com
c  unee.net
c  21cn.com iop.com foo.com bar.com baz.net happy2all.com
```

and so on.

So pushing the output of the previous sed into the new sed should eventually give you the required format.

I know this is probably not the optimal answer, I will try to refine it if possible.

Comment: thanks for your effort. but how can we know how many times I should run this sed line?  I didn't downvote your answer, but it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: You will have to put an rough upper limit on the maximum number of word-groups you think will occur on the line. I understand this may not be possible in your situation, but then again I am also not sure if this problem is solvable by sed in a single pass. I need to look at ω-automaton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton) and DFAs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) to understand if is possible. I will update the answer accordingly.