# Trying to change date string in a file to different format with sed

Tags: bash, date, sed

So i am trying to change all dates in a text file from

1-1-1111(Month,Day,Year)

to

January 1, 1111(Month,Day,Year)

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{4\}/date -d"+%B +%d, +%Y"/g'
```

I'm not sure how to format from "date" on. If I add other single quotes it won't function correctly. It is not functioning correctly as is but I know i want to use

```
date -d"+%B +%d, +%Y"
```

on the second half of

```
sed's///g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you use simple quote to protect the sed expression, that's why you CANNOT use other simple quote inside (there is no escape in this case).

If your sed is GNU sed. you can use 'e' to pass matched group to external command/tools within sed command as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719011/sed-pass-match-to-external-command).

But it means you call an external command for each match. So this solution can be slow if your text contains a lot of dates.

If you have only one date by line, I suggest the following script :

```
sed -r 's#([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})#date -d"\1/\2/\3" +"%B %d, %Y"#e'
```

Comment: I only have one date per line but I do have phone numbers and area codes as well.   I also get these errors   sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: So I think awk or perl are more suitable. Consider the choroba's answer. I can provide another example in awk if your prefer.

Comment: I have to use sed for it. I know nothing of the others but would agree that there are much better routes but for this purpose I have to use sed,tr,grep,cut,paste. I just figured I could go through with one swoop to amend the dates within a text document.

Comment: +1 If you're not changing the order of the fields, you don't really need to capture them. `date -d "$(sed 's#-#/#g' <<< "$d")" "+%B %e, %Y"` would suffice

Comment: Ahyone else spot the big red "homework" flag - `I have to use sed,tr,grep,cut,paste` :-). No real world shell problem is restricted to those tools since every UNIX installation comes with awk. Interesting the OP didn't list `date` as a usable tool...

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the sed script in bash to avoid calls to external tools:

```
#!/bin/bash

idx=12
for month in Dec Nov Oct Sep Aug Jul Jun May Apr Mar Feb Jan ; do
    echo "s/$idx-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/$month \1, \2/g"
    (( idx-- ))
done
```

Note that I use the months in reverse order to prevent `12` to be translated to `1Feb`.

Saved as `script.sh`, it generates the following sed script:

```
s/12-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Dec \1, \2/g
s/11-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Nov \1, \2/g
s/10-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Oct \1, \2/g
s/9-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Sep \1, \2/g
s/8-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Aug \1, \2/g
s/7-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Jul \1, \2/g
s/6-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Jun \1, \2/g
s/5-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/May \1, \2/g
s/4-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Apr \1, \2/g
s/3-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Mar \1, \2/g
s/2-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Feb \1, \2/g
s/1-\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/Jan \1, \2/g
```

Then, run

```
script.sh | sed -f- file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue (using [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece)):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 'BEGIN { @months = ( undef, Time::Piece::mon_list() ) }
                        s/([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})/$months[$1] $2, $3/g' < input > output
```

Comment: I have to use sed for it. I know nothing of the others but would agree that there are much better routes but for this purpose I have to use sed,tr,grep,cut,paste. I just figured I could go through with one swoop to amend the dates within a text document. Perl seems to be the ay to go for many things I'm doing but I have to use the above mentioned guildlines. Thank you sooo much though!