# Syntax error: "(" unexpected when using GNU sed with 'e' flag

Tags: bash, sed

### Desired end result

I'm trying to convert the following (MS-SQL) string

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
```

to SQLite syntax

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (-358491600)
```

### Approach

I'm successfully doing this with the following `sed` arguments:

```
sed -r "s#cast\('(.*)' as datetime\)#date -d '\1' '+%s'#ige"
```

(calling `date -d '...' '+%s'` to convert the date to epoch)

### Problem

Running the same command over the complete line:

```
echo "INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) values (cast('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' as datetime))" | \
    sed -r "s#cast\('(.*)' as datetime\)#date -d '\1' '+%s'#ige"
```

...produces an error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

From what I've tracked, parenthesis cause the line to fail:

```
echo "() cast('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' as datetime)" | \
    sed -r "s#cast\('(.*)' as datetime\)#date -d '\1' '+%s'#ige"
```

Removing the `e` switch properly converts the command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sed with `ge` flag does your job:

```
sed -r 's/(.*CAST[^\x27]*\x27)([^\x27]*)(\x27 AS DateTime.*)/
      echo "\1"$(date -d"\2" "+%s")"\3"/ge' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('1958-08-23 22:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
kent$  sed -r 's/(.*CAST[^\x27]*\x27)([^\x27]*)(\x27 AS DateTime.*)/echo "\1"$(date -d"\2" "+%s")"\3"/ge' file
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('-358488000' AS DateTime));
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('-358398000' AS DateTime));
```

if you don't want to have the `As DateTime` in output, just make proper groups, I think you can manage it.

Comment: Interesting implementation! But as far I understand it doesn't handle case when more than one date located on the same line.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin I think it could be done. well if we are talking about the "doability" only. we can nest `sed/awk/grep/....` in `sed`. just a matter of complexity. but it could be done by gnu sed.

Comment: The `echo $(date)` is a bit of a wart, though.  Provided there are no percent signs in the matched text, `date -d"\2" +"\1%s\3"` might be easier on the eyes and nerves.

Comment: Thanks, @Kent! You mean that doing global matches would require the expression to be like shown in [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11719531/25427), right?

Comment: @AlexGyoshev yes. You asked sed s/../../ge, so I answered it. but if the case is more complex, other way (perl/awk/script..) may better than sed.

Comment: Yup, marking it as answer since it answers the question. I ended up doing something similar to @SlavaSemushin's solution in the end (although via a node script). More verbose, but cleaner imo.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your command under `strace` to see what exacly will be executed you will see the following:

```
$  echo "INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) values (cast('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' as datetime))" | strace -ff sed -r "s#cast\('(.*)' as datetime\)#date -d '\1' '+%s'#ige" 2>&1 | grep 'execve('
execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "-r", "s#cast\\('(.*)' as datetime\\)#dat"...], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
[pid  8179] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) values (da"...], [/* 27 vars */] <unfinished ...>
```

It means that `sed` tries to execute not only text that was matched the pattern but the whole line.. So, probably, you can't do that with `sed` (I will be glad if I'm mistaken.)

So, I suggest to gather all dates from file, convert them and then replace one by one. For example:

```
$ cat q.sql
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('1958-08-22 21:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('1958-08-23 22:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
$ sed "s|.*CAST('\([^']\+\)'.*|\1|" q.sql | while read DATE; do sed -i "s|$DATE|$(date -d "$DATE" '+%s')|" q.sql; done
$ cat q.sql
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('-358495200' AS DateTime));
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES (CAST('-358405200' AS DateTime));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `strace` technique, very handy for debugging. The solution is nice, too (if I'm not wrong, combining `uniq` can make it even faster if there are many duplicates).