# sed: How to use a remembered pattern in an embedded shell command?

Tags: shell, sed, makefile, gnu-make, command-substitution

I have a GNU `makefile` with one of the recipe lines reading:

```
sed -i 's|<span class="math">$$\(.*\)$$</span>|<span style="font-size:100%">'"$$(curl -d "type=tex&q=\1" http://localhost:16000/)"'</span>|g' $(NAME).a4.xhtml
```

The idea is to replace `<span class="math">$$\(.*\)$$</span>`

by `<span style="font-size:100%">..SVG..</span>`

where `..SVG..` is the string returned by executing the shell command `curl -d "type=tex&q=\1" http://localhost:16000/` and where `\1` should be the previously remembered pattern `\(.*\)`.

**Problem:** Both the pattern detection and the shell execution are working alright. However, `\1` is not substituted by the previously remembered pattern.

PS: If one prefers to use `sed` with the `-r` option, matching inside the `makefile` is as follows:

```
sed -i -r 's@<span class="math">\$$(.*)\$$</span>@..@..' $(NAME).a4.xhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `shell substitution` within `sed` which obviously will not expand `\1` to the group match. One solution is to use sed's `e` command, a good explanation is given [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands).

If you need an example, refer the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719011/sed-pass-match-to-external-command).

Answer (score 0):

While I suppose it might be possible to pull this off with GNU `sed` with the `/e` extension, may I humbly suggest you use a different tool?

```
perl -i -MLWP::UserAgent -pe '
  BEGIN { $u = LWP::UserAgent->new(); }
  s|<span class="math">\$\$\(.*?\)\$\$</span>|
    sprintf q{<span style="font-size:100%%">%s</span>},
      $u->post("http://localhost:16000/",
        [type=>"tex", q=>"$1"])->decoded_content()
  |ge' $(NAME).a4.xhtml
```

(Hoping there's a simpler way to POST from Perl but just grabbed what I could find.  Maybe look at WWW::Mechanize instead if you have that.)